# copy a string function

Tags: c++, string

I've tried to implement my own copy string function in c++

```
void pcstrdup(const char* szStr, char* szStrCpy)
{
    int nLen = strlen(szStr);
    if (!nLen)
        throw "Error : attempt copying an empty string";
    ++nLen;
    szStrCpy = static_cast<char*>(malloc(sizeof(char) * nLen));
    if (!szStrCpy)
        throw "Error : memory allocation failed";
    for (int i = 0; i < nLen; i++)
    {
        szStrCpy[i] = szStr[i];
    }
}
```

I've debugged and checked that the characters are being copied and it copies them all but the \0 character, when it gets to that point I get an exception

```
Unhandled exception at 0x011A5BA1 in assignment2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

Which brings me to this function :

```
static size_t __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL length(const _Elem *_First)
    {   // find length of null-terminated string
    return (*_First == 0 ? 0
        : _CSTD strlen(_First));
    }
```

note that the istrlen() function, is a function I wrote.

```
int istrlen(const char* szStr)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; szStr[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why are there so many string copy questions tonight? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Why is it an error to copy an empty string?

Comment: "`szStrCpy = static_cast<char*>(malloc(sizeof(char) * nLen));`" I'm out. :(

Comment: @BaummitAugen what ? please tell me so I will know what to improve :(

Comment: Is there a reason you're using C functions like `malloc` in C++ ?

Comment: @Barmar Oh well. Guess it shows that I never used it in C++ ...

Comment: _istrlen() is a function I wrote_ -- where does that appear in the code?

Comment: @Barmar I didn't include it because it was working fine, but I've included it now just for the sake of it, I'm 99.99% sure it's not the problem

Comment: @Tugal.44 First of all, just use `std::string`, not `char*`. I guess you are somehow forced to write this function, so I guess this did not help. Then do not use `malloc`, use `new`. Also, do not use `new`, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Tugal.44 What does it have to do with anything? You never call `istrlen()`, so why does it matter?

Comment: You should include the whole function, along with the declaration and return.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'm limited to what I can use, char* and mallocs for now

Comment: @dasblinkenlight didn't notice some part was missing, done.

Comment: Don't use `NULL` to compare with a character, it should only be used to assign/compare pointers.

Comment: @Tugal.44 Ok, I kind of get why someone forces you to use `char*`. I would disagree with him, but well... But ***`malloc`*** in C++ code? Wtf is wrong with this guy?

Comment: @Barmar but NULL is just a macro of 0 no ? so what does it matter if I write != 0 to != NULL

Comment: `NULL` could be a pointer expression, e.g. `(void *)0`.

Comment: so when checking for the '\0' characters should I always check for 0 / '\0' instead of NULL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your function declaration:

```
void pcstrdup(const char* szStr, char* szStrCpy)
```

When you assign `szStrCpy` the memory, the caller does not see the change, because the pointer is passed by value. When your `pcstrdup` returns, the memory allocated to `szStrCpy` is lost, and the caller sees the old value (in this case, it looks like it's `NULL`).

You can fix this by passing `szStrCpy` by reference:

```
void pcstrdup(const char* szStr, char *&szStrCpy)
```

Better yet, you should return `szStrCpy` rather than taking it as a second parameter:

```
char *pcstrdup(const char* szStr)
```

Comment: He should really return szStrCpy from the function and omit the szStrCpy parameter from his function. So something more along the lines of `char *pcstrdup(const char* szStr)` . I did upvote your answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If I allocate memory space to a pointer inside this function it'll only point to this memory address in the function and will return pointing to the original address after the function returned ? what if I already allocated memory to the pointer outside of the function and then change the *value* of the address the pointer pointing at in the function, will the change remain after the function returned ? Also making it return char* instead won't make managing the pointers harder ?

Comment: because if I would then need to make a pointer to char pointer which is the returned char pointer if I would wish to get access to the returned pointer in the future so I could deallocate it no ? (follow-up)

Comment: @Tugal.44 - Both of your last two comments are reasons for *not* writing functions like this, and instead use `std::string`.  If you're going to write code like this, why not go whole hog and write your own string class?  Then you won't worry about who gets to delete what.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have to use char* :S

Comment: @Tugal.44 - Did you read the second part of my comment?  Write your own string class -- you're still using char* when you do so.  In addition, you'll learn much more than writing one-off low-level 'C' functions, and third, you no longer need to worry about when or who does deletion.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'll sure do it when I'll have better experience with the language :)

Comment: @Tugal.44 - There are plenty of links on SO on on the web that shows a simple String class (written properly).  I just won't be surprised when next you must write a "strcat", and then some other string function that could have been encapsulated in a class.  In any event, the questions you asked a few comments ago are reasons why you are almost forced to encapsulate it in a class.  Otherwise, you will have headaches managing the memory if the program is non-trivial.

Comment: Also, the language you had placed a tag on is `C++`, not C.  So it is with good reason why (if you must) write a string class, and not just write stand-alone, `C`-ish functions.  Don't just rush to learn the C way of doing things when your goal is to learn C++.

Comment: @Tugal.44 Correct, if you pass by value, the old value would remain in there after the function returns. As far as managing the memory goes, there is no difference between returning a pointer and setting it in a parameter passed by reference, because you need to free the pointer either way. If a pointer was pointing to some other memory location prior to re-assignment, the caller is in the best position to make the decision on freeing it, so it shouldn't be a task of `pcstrdup`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight oh wow .. until now I thought when I pass pointers to function they sort of pass by ref and not value, I've got confused with all the pointer concept but I just got it right in my head now, all data types are passed by value unless using the & operator when passing a variable into a function OK! and in the case of pointers if passed by value it'll just create a new pointer on the stack pointing to the same address of the passed pointer is pointing at. Hopefully I got it right now :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I would've continued with C but there's a reason I just jumped to C++, unfortunately I've got to learn C++ now and I'm limited on time